# Can I call a websocket in protractor tests?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, protractor

In some of my protractor tests, I want to manipulate the backend via a websocket call. I wrote a function  that is called, but the websocket instance is not known.

```
function setTime(url, theTime) {
  var socket = new WebSocket(url);
}
```

But here my tests is complaining WebSocket not defined

If I do before a

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
```

It complains too. How can I do websocket manipulation from in my test ?

Answer (score 0):

Aparently I got 2 issues here. First the WebSocket item is living inside the browser, so no need for inclusion. 
Second issue: If you need a require, it includes relative from the javascript file itself, not from the path where the protractor is running in(current working dir).